# Changing location of Clover instrumented classes

Tags: java, ant, clover

I'm using Clover 2.5 and I've got a target that will package up the binary files.  However, at the moment, it seems that the Clover instrumented classes are being generated in the same output directory as the un-instrumented classes that I wish to package up in a jar.

How do I go about creating a jar so that the instrumented classes are not included?  Is there a way to change where the instrumented classes are spat out? Or is the only way to package up a jar that does not include the instrumented classes is to re-compile everything again?

I tried using the **tmpdir** attribute of the **clover-setup** target but that did not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing this manually with Ant, use the [`<clover-instr>`](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER025/clover-instr) task instead of `<clover-setup>`.  `<clover-instr>` has a `destdir` attribute that is the "directory into which Clover will write an instrumented copy of the source code".

If you're using Eclipse to kick all of this off, the [Clover documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=107184770) says that you can "right click on your project and select properties, select Clover, select Compilation tab, select 'User specified folder' and then select a project directory where you wish instrumented classes [to be output]".

Comment: Have you a strategy for compiling real and instrumented source code, such that sonar code coverage can still process the non-instrumented classes via ANT?